# Determine TCP payload activity/statistics

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I'd like to lookup a counter of the TCP payload activity (total bytes received) either for a given file descriptor or a given interface.  Preferably the given file descriptor, but for the interface would be sufficient.  Ideally I'd really like to know about any bytes that have been ack-ed, even ones which I have not read into userspace (yet?).

I've seen the `TCP_INFO` feature of `getsockopt()` but none of the fields appear to store "Total bytes received" or "total bytes transmitted (acked, e.g.)" so far as I can tell.

I've also seen the `netlink` `IFLA_STATS`+`RTNL_TC_BYTES` and the `SIOCETHTOOL`+`ETHTOOL_GSTATS` `ioctl()` (`rx_bytes` field) for the interfaces, and those are great, but I don't think they'll be able to discriminate between the overhead/headers of the other layers and the actual payload bytes.

`procfs` has `/proc/net/tcp` but this doesn't seem to contain what I'm looking for either.

Is there any way to get this particular data?

EDIT: promiscuous mode has an unbearable impact on throughput, so I can't leverage anything that uses it.  Not to mention that implementing large parts of the IP stack to determine which packets are appropriate is beyond my intended scope for this solution.

The goal is to have an overarching/no-trust/second-guess of what values I store from recvmsg().

The Right Thing™ to do is to keep track of those values correctly, but it would be valuable to have a simple "Hey OS?  How many bytes have I *really* received on this socket?"

Comment: You can use `iptables` to do the counting. This answer be interesting though: http://superuser.com/a/264651

Comment: Can you use libpcap?
You can set a monitor interface and capture exactly the types of packet you want, then just increment a counter if those packets meet your criteria.

Answer (score 4):

One could also use ioctl call with SIOCINQ to get the amount of queued unread data in the receive buffer. Here is usage from the man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html

```
int value;
error = ioctl(tcp_socket_fd, SIOCINQ, &value);
```

For interface TCP stats, we can use " netstat -i -p tcp" to find stats on a per-interface basis.

Comment: This is pretty helpful.  It's not the whole shebang as I'd have hoped, but a great piece of info.

Comment: As long as we are discussing solutions, one could also consider extendng the IOCTL call in the TCP layer by adding a new IOCTL value. You can find the place where SIOCINQ is defined here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L535 . Basically, add a
new structure that would return you all the custom stats that you are looking for. Clearly, this would be way more efficient than promiscuous mode solutions. The obvious caveat is that one would need to compile the kernel for that, perhaps something your usecase may not allow you to do.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to define that as out-of-scope.  But maybe I should go to the trouble of submitting it upstream.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this for diagnosis, or for development?

If diagnosis, tcpdump can tell you exactly what's happening on the network, filtered by the port and host details.

If for development, perhaps a bit more information about what you're trying to achieve would help...

ifconfig  gives RX and TX totals.

ifconfig gets these details from /proc/net/dev (as you can see via strace ifconfig).

There are also the Send/Receive-Q values given by netstat -t, if that's closer to what you want.

Comment: Devleopment: I'd like to have an overarching/no-trust/second-guess of what values I store from `recvmsg()`.  `ifconfig` includes overhead from layers below TCP.  `netstat -t`'s Receive-Q value is plagued by a risk of sampling error.  How often could I possibly sample in order to get a reliable number?  How often is the value itself published to `procfs`?

Comment: I suspect that the procfs value is always up to date - it isn't really a file, it's generated on the fly.

Comment: Perhaps, if this is intended as an audit mechanism, you should put something in between the code doing the recv'ing and the code using the data.  Either in the same code, or a completely independent process that proxies the data on and keeps count of how much data goes past.  If it's not for audit, are you sure you wouldn't rather just keep count yourself of the bytes read so far?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the statistics in /proc/net/dev can help.  I am not familiar with counting payload versus full packets including headers, so that makes the question harder to answer.

As for statistics on individual file descriptors, I am not aware of any standard means to get that information.

If it's possible to control startup of the programs for which the statistics are needed, it is possible to use an "interceptor" library which implements its own read(), write(), sendto(), and recvfrom() calls, passthrough the calls to the standard C library (or directly to system call), keep counters of the activity, and find a way to publish those values.

Comment: do these number reset at some point ? Are these lifetime numbers ?

Comment: These numbers reset on system reboot.  There may be a way to reset them between reboots - if so, I expect a system utility or /proc interface would provide that functionality.  Also, if an interface is pluggable, the statistics should reset on removal and recreation of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to just count total RX/TX per interface (which is already available in ifconfig/iproute2 tools)...

If you look into /proc a bit more, you can get somewhat more information. More specifically `/proc/<pid>/net/dev`.

Sample output:

```
    Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
  eth0: 12106810846 8527175    0 15842    0     0          0    682866 198923814 1503063    0    0    0     0       0          0
    lo: 270255057 3992930    0    0    0     0          0         0 270255057 3992930    0    0    0     0       0          0
  sit0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

If you start looking, the information is coming from `net/core/net-procfs.c` from [Linux kernel](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/net/core/net-procfs.c?id=refs/tags/v3.10.10)  (procfs just uses this info). All of this of course means you need specific process to track.

You can either peruse information available in `/proc` or if you need something more stable, then duplicating net-procfs functionality specifically for your application might make sense.